# Why is my vertex buffer filled with random, incorrect data?

Tags: c++, directx11

I've been using the Graphics-Debugger of VS2012 to see why my triangle is not drawn. It seems to be a problem with my VertexBuffer since all other Buffers show the data I fed them, however, the VertexBuffer contains random data every time I restart the application:

```
The buffer format used is specified in the 'Graphics Object Table'.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Types:  bool, int, xint (an unsigned hex int), uint (unsigned int), int64, xint64, uint64, 
        byte, xbyte, ubyte, 2byte,  x2byte, u2byte, 4byte, x4byte, u4byte, 8byte, x8byte, u8byte,  
        half (a 16-bit float), half2, half3, half4, float, float2, float3, float4, double
Usage:  'float' or 'float3 xint half half xint'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Currently used format:  float
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

0   [0x00000000-0x00000003] |       +0.070048094
1   [0x00000004-0x00000007] |    +3.0548307e-043
2   [0x00000008-0x0000000b] |       +0.069985747
3   [0x0000000c-0x0000000f] |    +3.0548307e-043
4   [0x00000010-0x00000013] |       +0.069986284
5   [0x00000014-0x00000017] |    +3.0548307e-043
6   [0x00000018-0x0000001b] |       +0.069986284
7   [0x0000001c-0x0000001f] |    +3.0548307e-043
8   [0x00000020-0x00000023] |       +0.070065737
9   [0x00000024-0x00000027] |    +3.0548307e-043
10  [0x00000028-0x0000002b] |                 +0
11  [0x0000002c-0x0000002f] |                 +0
12  [0x00000030-0x00000033] |                 +0
13  [0x00000034-0x00000037] |                 +0
14  [0x00000038-0x0000003b] |                 +0
15  [0x0000003c-0x0000003f] |                 +0
16  [0x00000040-0x00000043] |    -4.3159552e+008
17  [0x00000044-0x00000047] |    -4.3160208e+008
```

Or

```
0   [0x00000000-0x00000003] |           +1.#QNAN
1   [0x00000004-0x00000007] |    +1.2331426e-043
2   [0x00000008-0x0000000b] |           +1.#QNAN
3   [0x0000000c-0x0000000f] |    +1.2331426e-043
4   [0x00000010-0x00000013] |           +1.#QNAN
5   [0x00000014-0x00000017] |    +1.2331426e-043
6   [0x00000018-0x0000001b] |           +1.#QNAN
7   [0x0000001c-0x0000001f] |    +1.2331426e-043
8   [0x00000020-0x00000023] |           +1.#QNAN
9   [0x00000024-0x00000027] |    +1.2331426e-043
10  [0x00000028-0x0000002b] |                 +0
11  [0x0000002c-0x0000002f] |                 +0
12  [0x00000030-0x00000033] |                 +0
13  [0x00000034-0x00000037] |                 +0
14  [0x00000038-0x0000003b] |                 +0
15  [0x0000003c-0x0000003f] |                 +0
16  [0x00000040-0x00000043] |    -4.3159552e+008
17  [0x00000044-0x00000047] |    -4.3160208e+008
```

As you can see, the last 8 lines are identical (this is always the case) whereas the rest varies randomly. However, even the last 8 entries are not entirely correct.

My InputLayout is set correctly according to the debugger:

```
SemanticName SemanticIndex Format                      InputSlot AlignedByteOffset InputSlotClass              InstanceDataStepRate 
POSITION     0             DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT 0         0                 D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA 0 
COLOR        0             DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT 0         12                D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA 0
```

Here is the Vertex-Struct

```
struct VERTEXPOSITIONCOLOR
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3   position;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3   color;

    static D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC* GetVertexLayout()
    {
        static D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
        {
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,
                0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,
                0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        };
        return layout;
    }

    static UINT GetNumElements(){ return 2; }
};
```

Here I fill my Vertex-Vector:

```
VERTEXPOSITIONCOLOR p;
p.position = XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
p.color    = XMFLOAT3(  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
m_vVertices.push_back( p );


p.position = XMFLOAT3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
p.color    = XMFLOAT3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
m_vVertices.push_back( p );


p.position = XMFLOAT3(  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
p.color    = XMFLOAT3(  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
m_vVertices.push_back( p );
```

with `m_vVertices` being of type `std::vector<VERTEXPOSITIONCOLOR>`.

And here I create the VertexBuffer:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = static_cast<UINT>( m_vVertices.size() * GetStrideSize() );
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
InitData.pSysMem = &m_vVertices; 
InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

HRESULT hr = m_spDevice->CreateBuffer( &bufferDesc, &InitData, &m_spVertexBuffer );
```

with `bufferDesc.ByteWidth` having the value `72` and `hr` having the value `S_OK` at the end. `m_spVertexBuffer` is of type `CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>`.

Finally I call:

```
UINT Strides[1];
UINT Offsets[1];
Strides[0] = GetStrideSize(); 
Offsets[0] = 0;
pd3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_spVertexBuffer.p, Strides, Offsets );
```

With `Strides[0]` having the value `24`. Here I also set all other buffers.

So what did I do wrong with the VertexBuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set `InitData.pSysMem` to `&m_vVertices`. That is setting the system memory pointer to the address the `vector` object; you want to point instead to the actual data *stored* in the vector object:

```
InitData.pSysMem = &m_vVertices[0];
```

Comment: actually you'll want to use the `m_vVertices.data()` method, I find that to be clearer in its intend

Comment: data would be clearer, but it's also C++11 only; the "&[0]" idiom is fairly prevalent if a bit ugly. You can also accomplish the same thing via various manipulations of front() and begin().